# Wordpress database custom query to validate data

Tags: sql, wordpress

I cant find any syntax for custom queries, use of $wpdb is new to me so can anyone help me solving this??

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   global $wpdb;
   $tablename='wp_form_subscribe';

   $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_form_subscribe   where     email=$wpdb->email" );
   if($myrows==0)
   {
    $data=array(
    'name' => $_POST['fullname'], 
    'age' => $_POST['age'],
    'email' => $_POST['email']);
    $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data);
    }
   else 
   {
     $status='User already subscribed';
   }
   $status='';
  }
```

Comment: Go through the following article : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress defines a class called `wpdb`, which contains a set of functions used to interact with a database.

[Reference Link for $wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

if you want to check the email in your table `wp_form_subscribe`

```
        $status='';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
         global $wpdb;

       $tablename = 'wp_form_subscribe';
       $email = esc_sql($_POST['email']);

       // Execute the Query
       $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_form_subscribe   where     email = '$email' " );
       // Check for row exists with the email you provided.

       $rowCount = $wpdb->num_rows;

      if($rowCount == 0 )
       {
        $data=array(
                     'name' => $_POST['fullname'], 
                     'age' => $_POST['age'],
                     'email' => $_POST['email'] 
                   );


      $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data);

      $status='User successfully subscribed';

      }
      else 
        {
    $status='User already subscribed';
         }
    echo $status;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Noman...i was confused in data entry in Wordpress but my doubts have cleared...we use $wpdb for entering the value..rest remains almost same...am i right??

Comment: not only for insert `$wpdb` which has wordpress methods like get_results, insert , update , see more for details. http://codepeach.com/wordpress/wordpress-database-interaction-wpdb/

Comment: is my answer correct ?

Comment: yes...it works ..and yes i meant just the query functions are changed